# React Sorting Dates in UTC format (e:2019-11-14T10:18:51Z)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, utc

i do have a json that do have DateModified as key and its value in UTC format.
I need a sort toggle button,so that on toggle it should sort based on this Date(latest on first)
Can anyone help me to figure it out .

Here is myJSON

```
{
  "jpg": [
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "450",
      "caption": "first",
      "id": "56",
      "height": "470",
      "url": "/services/asset/get/56/?token=",
      "name": "JPG.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-11-14T10:18:51Z"
    },
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "0",
      "caption": "second",
      "id": "47",
      "height": "0",
      "url": "",
      "name": "download--2.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-10-10T10:55:34Z"
    },
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "0",
      "caption": "second",
      "id": "47",
      "height": "0",
      "url": "",
      "name": "download--2.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-10-05T10:55:34Z"
    }]
```

Any jsfiddle will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data ={
  "jpg": [
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "450",
      "caption": "first",
      "id": "56",
      "height": "470",
      "url": "/services/asset/get/56/?token=",
      "name": "JPG.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-11-14T10:18:51Z"
    },
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "0",
      "caption": "second",
      "id": "47",
      "height": "0",
      "url": "",
      "name": "download--2.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-10-10T10:55:34Z"
    },
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "0",
      "caption": "second",
      "id": "47",
      "height": "0",
      "url": "",
      "name": "download--2.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-10-05T10:55:34Z"
    }]
}
let array = data.jpg;
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a.DateModified) - new Date(b.DateModified);
});
console.log(array)
```

For your reference in reactjs

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sort-array-of-objects-based-on-date-op3n8)

Comment: Hey Thanks for you reply. but will it work as toggle ? 
both ascending and descending  Dates

Comment: @midhunk hey, now you can check live demo working for both ascending and descending dates.

Comment: @midhunk if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/4mn2dept/

```js
const images = {
  "jpg": [
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "450",
      "caption": "first",
      "id": "56",
      "height": "470",
      "url": "/services/asset/get/56/?token=",
      "name": "JPG.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-11-14T10:18:51Z"
    },
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "0",
      "caption": "second",
      "id": "47",
      "height": "0",
      "url": "",
      "name": "download--2.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-10-10T10:55:34Z"
    },
    {
      "extension": "jpg",
      "width": "0",
      "caption": "second",
      "id": "47",
      "height": "0",
      "url": "",
      "name": "download--2.jpg",
      "DateModified": "2019-10-05T10:55:34Z"
  }]
}
const result = images.jpg.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.DateModified) - new Date(a.DateModified))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: :i got the solution,but its console things,any options on first click it sort of latest on another it again on last,exactly like a toggle

Comment: you can create 2 version of this function. one something like: 
`
const sortAsc = () =>{...}
const sortDesc = () => {...}
images.jpg.sort( asc ? sortAsc : sortDesc)
`